# Problems parsing XML with XSL in it

Tags: android, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

When trying to read my xml from a webpage i get: "Error: At line 8, column 23: unbound prefix"
Below is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<outertag>
<innertag sampleattribute="innertagAttribute">
    <Retailer>
        RetailerName:
        <xsl:template match="link">
            <a href="LinkGoesHere">Link</a>
        </xsl:template>
    </Retailer>
</innertag>
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong? Can I not use xsl:template within my xml? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem and for an easy and short, but complete solution. :)

Comment: As the subsequent dialogue shows, the "unbound prefix" error was just a symptom; the underlying cause of the problem is that you haven't understood the relationship of XSLT to XML. The simple answer is, if you're sending XML to the browser, NO: you can't simply include XSLT instructions in the XML and expect them to be executed.

Comment: @Michael Kay: With respect, Dr. Kay, but you can also use [embedded stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Embedding-Stylesheets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When trying to read my xml from a
>   webpage i get: "Error: At line 8,
>   column 23: unbound prefix" Below is my
>   xml:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <outertag>
>   <innertag sampleattribute="innertagAttribute">
>       <Retailer>RetailerName: 
>           <xsl:template match="link">
>               <a href="LinkGoesHere">Link</a>
>           </xsl:template>
>       </Retailer>
>   </innertag>
> </outertag>
> ```
>
> Any ideas as to what is wrong? Can I
>   not use xsl:template within my xml?

The provided document is not well-formed and the error message very well says what is the reason:

There is an element named `xsl:template`, however there is no namespace declaration in the whole document that binds the prefix `xsl:` to any namespace.

**Solution**:

Correct the non-well-formed text to a well-formed XML document by providing a namespace declaration for the XSLT namespace:

```
<outertag>
    <innertag sampleattribute="innertagAttribute">
        <Retailer>RetailerName: 
            <xsl:template match="link"
             xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                <a href="LinkGoesHere">Link</a>
            </xsl:template>
        </Retailer>
    </innertag>
</outertag>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not end up working the way I had hoped. Your solution did end up fixing the formatting problem, but i cannot get Android to recognize the link in the xml. As can be seen in my example code, I am trying to have an xml file with a list of links be parsed by Android with the links still being clickable. Do you have any suggestions on how I could do this? Right now I am stuck using webview which I don't particularly like because I return quite a bit of data.

Comment: You should probably post that as a separate question.

Comment: @BlakeJ, your question has been answered. Accept the answer and post another question. You can't add requirements on the fly.

Comment: @BlakeJ: Whenever XSLT is involved one must know and define: 1. The XML document to be transformed (a minimal full XML is needed). 2. The exact results wanted from the transformation of the XML document specified in 1, and 3. Any desired rules/properties of the transformation, such as what input items are used in what way to prodyce an output item. Please, specify all these in a new question. Your original question has been answered completely. Please, according to the practices of SO, consider accepting and upvoting my answer.